# How to subset a df with a vector of dates and getting all the matching data?

Tags: r

I am trying to subset my df bases on matching dates. I have the dates i require with the date format. The date on my df is on the same format.
When I try my code I am getting only the first row matching the subset and there could be 20 matching rows per date.

I tried using subset with a logical search in the df matching the vector

```
subset.met=subset(hr.met, hr.met$date == dates)
```

**This is my df**

```
1 2018-12-20 07:00:00 NA 984.3140 4.7425 4.240365 203.2252
2 2018-12-20 08:00:00 NA 986.6738 2.6975 2.036287 175.7522
3 2018-12-20 09:00:00 NA 988.1152 3.7025 3.411026 212.9876
4 2018-12-20 10:00:00 NA 989.2403 3.7700 3.297027 216.7082
5 2018-12-20 11:00:00 NA 990.4552 4.0250 3.511919 225.3250
6 2018-12-20 12:00:00 NA 990.5790 3.7175 3.317329 222.5587
       dwd t2 rh sat vp h2o       date
1 24.77761 NA NA  NA NA  NA 2018-12-20
2 41.94633 NA NA  NA NA  NA 2018-12-20
3 21.79864 NA NA  NA NA  NA 2018-12-20
4 28.37998 NA NA  NA NA  NA 2018-12-20
5 27.86019 NA NA  NA NA  NA 2018-12-20
6 25.02467 NA NA  NA NA  NA 2018-12-20
```

**This is my dates vector**

```
"2019-02-06" "2019-02-07" "2019-02-08" "2019-02-11" "2019-02-12" "2019-02-13" "2019-02-15" "2019-02-16" "2019-02-17" "2019-02-18"
"2019-02-20" "2019-02-21" "2019-02-26" "2019-02-27" "2019-02-28" "2019-03-01" "2019-03-02" "2019-03-03" "2019-03-04" "2019-03-05"
"2019-03-12" "2019-03-13" "2019-03-14" "2019-03-15" "2019-03-16" "2019-03-17" "2019-03-19"
```

**This is what I am getting**

```
1004 2019-01-31 02:00:00       NA  990.8791 2.880833 2.716300
1042 2019-02-01 16:00:00       NA 1001.9768 1.759167 1.652109
1081 2019-02-03 07:00:00       NA  994.9080 3.465000 3.127165
1119 2019-02-04 21:00:00       NA  997.8129 3.465000 3.115460
1158 2019-02-06 12:00:00 296.4433  999.6472 2.322500 2.196016
1197 2019-02-08 03:00:00 306.4103  987.3516 2.096667 1.946248
            wd      dwd       t2       rh      sat       vp
1004  16.40826 18.24759       NA       NA       NA       NA
1042 213.26311 17.81623       NA       NA       NA       NA
1081  29.44621 24.45101       NA       NA       NA       NA
1119 203.37526 24.97175       NA       NA       NA       NA
1158  25.21708 17.95901 297.0304 82.88533 29.61701 24.54474
1197  27.73385 20.24611 306.8247 39.54208 52.31900 20.19168
          h2o       date
1004       NA 2019-01-31
1042       NA 2019-02-01
1081       NA 2019-02-03
1119       NA 2019-02-04
1158 993.8726 2019-02-06
1197 791.6034 2019-02-08
```

If you can see I am getting only the first matching row of every date, and I need all the rows.

Comment: use `%in%`, `subset.met=subset(hr.met, date %in% dates)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a logical vector which checks if the `dates` are present as below:

```
hr.met$date %in% dates
grepl(dates, hr.met$date)
```

And then subset using that vector like:

```
subset(hr.met, date %in% dates)
dplyr::filter(hr.met, date %in% dates)
hr.met[grepl(dates, hr.met$date), ]
```